# Checking if the program has rights to move a file

Tags: c#

C# Doesnt allow me to acces some files because they are either already in use OR i dont have the right to open them.

Could it be possible to get it to check if a program is running OR if it doesnt have acces to this file BEFORE it gives an error?

Greetings
Luna xx

Comment: Even if you were to check that, there is no guarantee that by the time you try to open them that you still have those rights. The best way to handle IO is to just do it and deal with an exception if-any. In short: its out of your control.

Comment: File in use, you will never know. Right to open it, that [you could check](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.getaccesscontrol?view=netframework-4.7.2).